# No matching version found for protractor@~5.4.0

Tags: protractor, angular-cli

I tried to follow the angular cli tutorial for creating an Angular app. However, it is throwing an error on protractor 5.4.0.

here is the error message:

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for protractor@~5.4.0
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
npm ERR! notarget
npm ERR! notarget It was specified as a dependency of 'angulartest6'
npm ERR! notarget
```

The latest version of protractor is 5.4.0. I also tried to install manually but it is throwing this error:
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for protractor@5.4.0

What is the workaround so that I don't get this error?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding the following to your `package.json`file:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "protractor": "5.4.0"
  }
```

Comment: it's a devdependency and automatically included when you create an app using angular cli command. This works in my windows 7 laptop but not in my windows 10. I wonder if that was the issue.